# retrieve an id from url to controller without using route parameter ? Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve an id from url without using route parameter, for example I wanted to retrieve an id from this url : `{{ url('edisi/' . $edisi->id) }}` is there a way how to retrieve the id without using route parameter ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`segment()` method](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segment). If URL is `edisi/someparameter`, you can use `Request::segment(2)` to get `someparameter`.

Comment: so in my case : jurnal/create?edisi=1 it would be Request::segment(2) as well ?

Comment: You've shown another example in you question, so `segment(2)` will get `create` from URL you posted in comment. If you want to get parameter, do this `$edisi = Input::get('edisi', false);`

Comment: Hey Alexey you still there ? I got another problem if you don't mind to take a look :)